# Unexpected data_runfiles of filegroup appearing in aspect

Tags: bazel

I have an aspect like this:

```
def _foo_aspect_impl(target, aspect_ctx):
    fail("KIND: {}, DATA_RUNFILES: {}".format(aspect_ctx.rule.kind, [p.path for p in target.data_runfiles.files]))
```

which fails with the error:

```
KIND: filegroup, DATA_RUNFILES: [<hugelistofsrcsfiles>]
```

What puzzles me is that I never declared `data` files on this `filegroup`. So I am wondering where these are coming from. I absolutely do not want them here.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [Filegroup code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/612db22a4df8708e48552795d086f0f41b2e4531/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/filegroup/Filegroup.java#L78), the filegroups declare only one kind of runfile provider: data runfiles provider. I guess you might want to open a feature request on [Github](http://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues) and have a proper discussion of what you want there.

Comment: BTW: Is there any documentation about what a data runfile is in contrast to a default runfile?